# Text to speech Azure service: Speech is not working (not talking) C#

Tags: c#, .net, azure, text-to-speech, speech

I'm trying to use the Text to Speech service on Microsoft azure and I used the official documentation and the official code using c# language but whenever I enter a value to let the program speak nothing happen not even an error message.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech;
using Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.Audio;

class Program 
{

static string speechKey = "";
static string speechRegion = "";

static void OutputSpeechSynthesisResult(SpeechSynthesisResult speechSynthesisResult, string text)
{
    switch (speechSynthesisResult.Reason)
    {
        case ResultReason.SynthesizingAudioCompleted:
            Console.WriteLine($"Speech synthesized for text: [{text}]");
            break;
        case ResultReason.Canceled:
            var cancellation = SpeechSynthesisCancellationDetails.FromResult(speechSynthesisResult);
            Console.WriteLine($"CANCELED: Reason={cancellation.Reason}");

            if (cancellation.Reason == CancellationReason.Error)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"CANCELED: ErrorCode={cancellation.ErrorCode}");
                Console.WriteLine($"CANCELED: ErrorDetails=[{cancellation.ErrorDetails}]");
                Console.WriteLine($"CANCELED: Did you set the speech resource key and region values?");
            }
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
async static Task Main(string[] args)
{
    var speechConfig = SpeechConfig.FromSubscription(speechKey, speechRegion);      

    // The language of the voice that speaks.
    speechConfig.SpeechSynthesisVoiceName = "en-US-JennyNeural"; 

    using (var speechSynthesizer = new SpeechSynthesizer(speechConfig))
    {
        // Get text from the console and synthesize to the default speaker.
        Console.WriteLine("Enter some text that you want to speak >");
        string text = Console.ReadLine();
        var speechSynthesisResult = await speechSynthesizer.SpeakTextAsync(text);
        OutputSpeechSynthesisResult(speechSynthesisResult, text);
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit...");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
}
```

whenever I run the app and I type anything nothing happens

[here is the output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mRQwN.png)

Answer (score 0):

**I tried in my environment and got below results:**
I executed the same code in my environment and got error:

**Console:**
[image]

**Output:**
[image]

The above error is ongoing issue with Microsoft azure in that they have mentioned the Speech SDK latest impacting the wide variety of TLS-dependent service use started failing. This error only occurs in Windows other API and MacOS has been working properly.

You can use this code get the **`(text to speech)`**

**Code:**

```
using Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech;
using Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.Audio;
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
namespace TextToSpeech
{
    class Program
    {
        async static Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            await ProcessSpeech();
            Console.WriteLine("Completed");
        }
        async static Task ProcessSpeech()
        {
            var l_speechConfig = SpeechConfig.FromEndpoint(new Uri("< endpoint>"), "key");
            var l_audioConfig = AudioConfig.FromWavFileOutput("C:\\Users\\v-vsettu\\download1\\new1.wav");
            var l_synthesizer = new SpeechSynthesizer(l_speechConfig, l_audioConfig);
            await l_synthesizer.SpeakTextAsync("Hi siri");
        }
    }
}
```

***Console:***
[image]

**File:**
[image]

Please refer this [MS-Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1047034/text-to-speech-usp-error-timeout-waiting-for-the-f-1.html) for ongoing problem in **`Speech-SDK`** for more information.